# JavaScript Help! Script not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this script to work, but it is failing somewhere in the last alert. The script is supposed to pull everything from a form, and then spit out the results as an alert box. I'm pretty sure my html is correct.

```
function calcServiceTotal() {
var animalName = document.getElementById("name").value;
var ownerName = document.getElementById("owner").value;
var currentDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
var choosenService = document.getElementById("service");
var serviceName = choosenService.options[choosenService.selectedIndex].text;
var serviceCost = document.getElementById("value").value;
var taxCost = serviceCost * 0.07;
var totalCost = serviceCost + taxCost;
if (animalName == null || animalName == "")
    {
    alert("Please give us your pet's name.");
    return false;
    }
else if (ownerName == null || ownerName == "")
    {
    alert("Please give us your name.");
    return false;
    }
else if (currentDate== null || currentDate == "")
    {
    alert("Please give us a date.");
    return false;
    }
else
    {
    alert("Pet's Name:" + animalName + '\n' + "Owner's Name:" + ownerName + '\n' + "Service:" + choosenService + '\n' + "Cost: $" + serviceCost.toFixed(2) + '\n' + "Tax: $" + taxCost.toFixed(2) + "Total Cost:" + totalCost.toFixed(2));
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant html code.

```
<table width="339" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="329"><strong>Patient Information</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label for="textfield"></label>      <input type="text" name="textfield" id="name" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Owner: &nbsp; 
            <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="owner" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Date: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="textfield3" id="date" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Services</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
              Select a Service:
              <label for="select"></label>
              <select name="select" id="service">
                <option>Basic Appointment - $50</option>
                <option>Extended Appointment - $75</option>
                <option>Vacination - $25</option>
                <option>Grooming - $35</option>
                <option>Bathing - $35</option>
                </select>
            </form></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Service Fee (from above): &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <label for="textfield4"></label>
                <input type="text" name="textfield4" id="value" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
              <input type="button" onclick="calcServiceTotal();" name="button" id="button" value="calculate"/>
            </form></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please take some time to review the [faq]. You might notice, that while you are writing a question that the preview of what the question looks like will appear below the question itself. It would be ever so kind if you could make sure to format your code to be presentable. Don't be in a rush to submit your question too early, take your time and review it thoroughly before hitting the submit button.

Comment: Additionally, using a service such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for questions where you have large chunks of HTML, CSS & JS would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using a function that is not defined, namely `toFixed()`

It is easy to find these errors if you use a debugging tool such as Firebug:

[image]

To clarify, `toFixed` is a function, but even though Javascript is loosely typed, in the context it's supplied your are applying `toFixed` to a string (for which it is undefined) and in this context the string cannot be coerced into a number.

You must specify it manually, by changing your last alert to:

`alert("Pet's Name:" + animalName + '\n' + "Owner's Name:" + ownerName + '\n' + "Service:" + choosenService + '\n' + "Cost: $" + Number(serviceCost).toFixed(2) + '\n' + "Tax: $" + Number(taxCost).toFixed(2) + "Total Cost:" + Number(totalCost).toFixed(2));`

Note that there are other errors in your code, such as concatenating two string values (which store Numbers) instead of addition.

Comment: toFixed() is a function, but for a number; like so: Number(document.getElementById("value").value).toFixed()

Answer (score 0):

I removed some bugs:

```
function calcServiceTotal() {
    var animalName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var ownerName = document.getElementById("owner").value;
    var currentDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var choosenService = document.getElementById("service").value;
    var serviceCost = Number(document.getElementById("value").value);
    var taxCost = serviceCost * 0.07;
    var totalCost = serviceCost + taxCost;
    if (animalName == null || animalName == "") {
        alert("Please give us your pet's name.");
        return false;
    } else if (ownerName == null || ownerName == "") {
        alert("Please give us your name.");
        return false;
    } else if (currentDate== null || currentDate == "") {
        alert("Please give us a date.");
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("Pet's Name:" + animalName + '\n' + "Owner's Name:" + ownerName + '\n' + "Service:" + choosenService + '\n' + "Cost: $" + serviceCost.toFixed(2) + '\n' + "Tax: $" + taxCost.toFixed(2) + "Total Cost:" + totalCost.toFixed(2));
    }


<table width="339" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="329"><strong>Patient Information</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label for="textfield"></label>      <input id="name" type="text" name="textfield" id="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Owner: &nbsp; 
        <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="owner" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="textfield3" id="date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Services</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
                Select a Service:
                <label for="select"></label>
                <select name="select" id="service">
                    <option value="Basic Appointment - $50">Basic Appointment - $50</option>
                    <option value="Extended Appointment - $75">Extended Appointment - $75</option>
                    <option value="Vacination - $25">Vacination - $25</option>
                    <option value="Grooming - $35">Grooming - $35</option>
                    <option value="Bathing - $35">Bathing - $35</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Service Fee (from above): &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <label for="textfield4"></label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield4" id="value" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
                <input type="button" onclick="calcServiceTotal();" name="button" id="button" value="calculate"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am not using choosenService.selectedIndex